# bootstrap carousel autoplay,start videos when slide activates

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use Bootstrap carousel with videos. I have a list of videos of 5 sec. I need to auto-play them using this carousel.

Currently , Bootstrap plays the very first video but I also wish to automatically play all the others when they slide into the screen.

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/wxMrf/20/

Code :

```
 var $myCarousel = $("#myCarousel");
   $myCarousel.carousel({
      interval: 2000
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I checked the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wxMrf/20/) you have created and you seem to embed the video in an `iframe`. Assuming you have the complete url of the video file resource available with you, you might want to try encapsulating them in a `video` tag supported by HTML5. It has an `autoplay` option associated with it and is supported in all major browsers today (upto IE8).

From [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_autoplay.asp), you could try something like this in context of your code:

```
  <div class="item">
    <div class="container">
     <div class="flex-video widescreen" style="margin: 0 auto;text-align:center;">4
       <video controls autoplay>
         <source src="foobar.mp4" type="video/mp4">
         Your browser does not support the video tag.
      </video>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Ofcourse, using the `video` tag limits browser compatibility to some extent which is the whole purpose of using an `iframe`in the first place. That's something you can decide. Also, if you are embedding videos from Youtube or Vimeo in an `iframe`, they almost certainly have an `autoplay` option in their videos. You should probably read up the relevant docs to get started on that. Hope this helps you out.

Comment: i need to play videos of my domain .

Comment: Ok, then it's better that you use the `video` tag like a suggested and just using the appropriate `src` attribute to link your video files. Try to adapt the code snippet I gave, in your carousel and play around with the `autoplay` option.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$myCarousel.on('slid', function() {
    console.log("Slide occur");
    //play video
});​
```

> **Note:** I think you are using Iframe to play video, so for playing video using this function, you can simply reload Iframe src.

Answer (score 1):

I have created the working jsFiddle, however while accessing 'video' element within iframe throws *cross-origin-request* security exception.

To overcome this start Chrome with following command,

```
chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files --disable-web-security
```

Open http://jsfiddle.net/wxMrf/21/ and see it working

Basically the solution is on the same line what 'Manwal' suggested,

```
$('#myCarousel').bind('slid', function (e) {
  $('.item.active').find('iframe').contents().find('body').find('video')[0].play();
});
```

Comment: it is playnig only first video? i need tp play them all on active state

Comment: Not just first, it plays the video whenever slide containing it becomes active.. But for that you need to start Chrome as mentioned..

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

```
$('#myCarousel').bind('slid', function (e) {
  $('.item.active').find('iframe').contents().find('body').find('video')[0].play();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, though please add an explanation on why your answer solves the OP's question. Also, please format your code correctly :)